# Changing speech synthesizer language and reading it

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a description form that contain labels and 3 buttons(btntts,btnstop and btnchinese), I have also referenced `System.Speech.dll` already. As seen from the code below, when clicked it will draw the data that contains the chinese description from the database to populate the labels.

```
private void btnchinese_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnchinese.Text == "Chinese")
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {
                    sqlcon.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("Select * from DishRepresentation WHERE Dish_ID='" + lblid.Text + "' and DishLanguage='Chinese'", sqlcon))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader sqldr = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
                        sqldr.Read();
                        lbldescription.Text = sqldr["DishDescription"].ToString();
                        lbldishname.Text = sqldr["DishName"].ToString();
                        lbldisheatbenefit.Text = sqldr["DishHealthBenefit"].ToString();
                        lblbenefit.Text = sqldr["DishBenefit"].ToString();
                        lblbenefit2.Text = sqldr["DishBenefit2"].ToString();
                        lblbenefit3.Text = sqldr["DishBenefit3"].ToString();
                        lblbenefit4.Text = sqldr["DishBenefit4"].ToString();
                        lblbenefit5.Text = sqldr["DishBenefit5"].ToString();
                    }
                }

                btnchinese.Text = "英语";
                btnstopspeech.Text = "停止阅读";
```

As for btntts, it will read the text populated.(Code Below)

```
private void btnTTS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pbuilder = new PromptBuilder();
            speaker2 = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            if (btnchinese.Text == "英语")
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-CN");
                var voices = speaker2.GetInstalledVoices(culture);
                speaker.Rate = -2;
                pbuilder.AppendText(lbldishname.Text);
                SetTimer(2000);
                pbuilder.AppendText(lbldescription.Text);
                speaker2.SpeakAsync(pbuilder);
            }
            else if (btnchinese.Text == "Chinese")
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
                var voices = speaker2.GetInstalledVoices(culture);
                speaker.Rate = -2;
                pbuilder.AppendText(lbldishname.Text);
                SetTimer(2000);
                pbuilder.AppendText(lbldescription.Text);
                speaker2.SpeakAsync(pbuilder);
            }
        }
```

NOTE: When the label is populated using english, btntts works as required and read the labels to the user. However it will not read, when it is populated with chinese. How can I make it read chinese as well?

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the voice. So it will use the default voice (in this case, an English voice) to read the text.

Use [SelectVoice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.selectvoice(v=vs.110).aspx) to set the voice.

> Use the GetInstalledVoices method and VoiceInfo class to obtain the names of installed text-to-speech (TTS) voices that you can select. To select a voice, pass the entire contents of the Name property as the argument for the SelectVoice method.

```
var pbuilder = new PromptBuilder();
var speaker2 = new SpeechSynthesizer();
speaker2.Rate = -2;

var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-CN");
var voices = speaker2.GetInstalledVoices(culture);
if (voices.Count > 0) //Chinese voices found
{
    speaker2.SelectVoice(voices[0].VoiceInfo.Name); //you need to call this API
    pbuilder.AppendText("hello 你好");   
    speaker2.SpeakAsync(pbuilder);
}
```

Comment: What does it mean by the name property? I have tried including the variables but it does not work

Comment: See my updated answer. In my code example, if Chinese voices are found, the first (voices[0]) Chinese voice will be selected. The API takes the Name of the voice as parameter.

Comment: It's weird, while debugging clearly your code is able to help me find count=1 [0] = "Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (zh-CN, HuiHui)" ["Enabled"] . However it's still unable to read '你好'

Comment: @ShaunTanJunKai can this voice be used as the Narrator voice? Try it. Or you can install Chinese language pack and try other Chinese voices.